# Automapper - Convert NameValueCollection to Strongly Typed Collection

Tags: automapper

In automapper, how would I map a namevalue collection to a strongly typed collection?

```cs
Mapper.Map<NameValueCollection, List<MetaModel>>();

public class MetaModel
{
     public string Name;
     public string Value;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Piggybacking off of [@dtryon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9360418/497356), the tough part about this is that there's no way to map the internal objects in `NameValueCollection` to your DTO type.

One thing you could do is write a [custom converter](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/05/06/automapper-feature-custom-type-converters/) that constructs `KeyValuePair<string, string>` objects from the items in the `NameValueCollection`. This would allow you to create a generic converter that leverages another mapping from `KeyValuePair` to a destination type of your choosing. Something like:

```cs
public class NameValueCollectionConverter<T> : ITypeConverter<NameValueCollection, List<T>>
{
    public List<T> Convert(ResolutionContext ctx) 
    {
        NameValueCollection source = ctx.SourceValue as NameValueCollection;

        return source.Cast<string>()
            .Select (v => MapKeyValuePair(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(v, source[v])))
            .ToList();
    }

    private T MapKeyValuePair(KeyValuePair<string, string> source) 
    {
        return Mapper.Map<KeyValuePair<string, string>, T>(source);
    }
}
```

Then you would need to define a mapping from `KeyValuePair<string, string>` to `MetaModel`:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<KeyValuePair<string, string>, MetaModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Key))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Value));
```

And finally, create a mapping between `NameValueCollection` and `List<MetaModel>`, using the custom converter:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<NameValueCollection, List<MetaModel>>()
    .ConvertUsing<NameValueCollectionConverter<MetaModel>>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, since NameValueCollection is so *special*, I don't think there is a good way to do this.  This is mostly due to the fact that you can't get a handle on a key/value object inside the NameValueCollection.  Luckily the code to map to the `List<MetaModel>` is not that bad.  I would just map it manually and continue working:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        List<MetaModel> dest = new List<MetaModel>();
        NameValueCollection src = new NameValueCollection();

        src.Add("Key1", "Value1");
        src.Add("Key2", "Value2");
        src.Add("Key3", "Value3");
        src.Add("Key4", "Value4");
        src.Add("Key5", "Value5");

        foreach (var srcItem in src.AllKeys)
        {
            dest.Add(new MetaModel() { Name = srcItem, Value = src[srcItem] });
        }

        Assert.AreEqual(5, dest.Count);

    }
```

Comment: +1, although you could wrap this in a custom resolver to make it a bit more reusable